# Mutations queries graphql-java

Tags: java, postman, graphql, graphql-java

I'm new to graphql specially graphql-java I have done queries with arguments successfully but when I try to send a mutation query the schema does not even execute the datafetcher is like not even been evaluated by the server. this is some snippets of my code.

```
DataFetcher nodeCreateDataFetcher = new DataFetcher(){
    public Object get(DataFetchingEnvironment environment) {

        Map source = (Map) environment.getSource();
        String alias = (String) source.get("alias");

        System.out.println(alias);
        //This statement adds a new node with a name on an alias class field
        Node node = getNodes.addNode(alias);
        return node;
    }
};

// Creates an InputobjectType
public GraphQLInputObjectType createNodeInputType(){
    return  newInputObject()
            .name("nodeInput")
            .field(newInputObjectField()
                    .name("alias")
                    .type(GraphQLString))
            .build();   
}

//Creates the Mutation schema
public GraphQLObjectType createMutation(){
    return newObject()
            .name("Mutation")
            .field(newFieldDefinition()
                .name("create")
                .type(createNodeType())
                .argument(newArgument()
                        .name("node")
                        .type(createNodeInputType())
                        .defaultValue("{alias: \"node4\"}"))
                .dataFetcher(nodeCreateDataFetcher))    
            .build();
}
```

So I go to postman and write something like this `{create(node:{alias:"anything"})}` this seems to be wrongs I see people using variable most of the time in graphql queries but I'm trying to do the simples mutation query and then start from there. I would really appreciate you help.

Answer (score 2):

I just overlooked one important part of the specification actually I had to write mutation before the query like `mutation {create(node:{alias:"anything"})}`